# Create Remote Consumer for JMS Queue in standalone app

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, glassfish-4, java-ee-7

I have a JMS implementation (producer and consumer) in my server Glashfish 4. 
The consumer code works when I executed as appclient in glashfish.

**Producer.java**

```
@Resource(lookup = "java:comp/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory")
private static ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
@Resource(lookup = "jms/MyQueue")
private static Queue queue;
...
JMSContext context = connectionFactory.createContext();
context.createProducer().send((Destination) queue, message);
```

**Consumer.java**

```
@Resource(lookup = "java:comp/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory")
private static ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
@Resource(lookup = "jms/MyQueue")
private static Queue queue;

...
JMSConsumer consumer;
JMSContext context = connectionFactory.createContext();
consumer = context.createConsumer((Destination) queue);
Message m = consumer.receive(1000);
```

I need make a consumer remote standalone java app.

In my glassfish server, I edited properties of JMS Connection Factory and I added property addressList with value x.x.x.x:xxxx

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First in your lib folder of your standalone java app copy file gf-client.jar.
The location of this file is your_glassfish_installation_directory/glassfish/lib.

Code

```
Properties props = new Properties();

props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial",
        "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");



// optional.  Defaults to localhost.  Only needed if web server is running
// on a different host than the appserver   
props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "localhost");

// optional.  Defaults to 3700.  Only needed if target orb port is not 3700.
props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(props);
QueueConnectionFactory cf =  (QueueConnectionFactory)ic.lookup("jms/MyConnectionFactory");
Queue queue =(Queue)ic.lookup("jms/queue");
```